# Question about Lie derivative of connection

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, vector-fields

This is from Hughston and Tod, Ex 8.5. Please give me an idea how to start with this.

> If $\mathcal{L}_V g_{ij} = 2\phi g_{ij}$ then prove that 
>   $$
> \mathcal{L}_V\Gamma^{i}_{jk} = \phi_{,j}\delta^{i}_{k} + \phi_{,k}\delta^{i}_{j} - g_{jk}\phi^{,i}.
> $$

I was thinking we could expand the connection in terms of the metric and then use Liebniz but I don't think the Lie derivative would commute past the derivative on the metric.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.